# ggplot2 geom_bar plot where ..count.. greater than X

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do i tell ggplot to to plot points only if count is greater than **X**. I know this should be easy but i couldnt figure it out. something like

```
ggplot(items,aes(x=itemname,y=..count..))+geom_bar(y>X)
```

Comment: `ggplot(items[items$y > items$x, ], ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (you haven't provided example data), the easiest way is to generate your the data frame you want to plot outside of ggplot. So

```
##Example data
items = data.frame(itemname = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 30, replace=TRUE))
##Use table to count elements
items_sum = as.data.frame(table(items))
```

Then plot

```
X = 4
ggplot(items_sum[items_sum$Freq > X,], aes(x=items,y=Freq)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Comment: This is a sort of question we get a lot on SO, and the answer is usually "shape your data, THEN use ggplot."

Comment: I was hoping may be ggplot would be having some sort of inbuilt filtering on data which it calculates, like in case of geom_bar the **count** of records which ggplot calls **..count..**. But i may be having some wrong notion on how its supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken here, but can't you simply pass the subset code to through geom_bar()?

```
ggplot(items_sum, aes(x=items,y=Freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", subset=.(Freq>4))
```