# Subset data frame based on top N most frequent values in variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, subset, ranking

My objective is to create a simple density or barplot of a long dataframe which shows the relative frequency of nationalities in a course (MOOC). I just don't want all of the nationalities in there, just the top 10. I created this example df below + the ggplot2 code I use for plotting.

```
d=data.frame(course=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500,replace=T),nationality=as.factor(sample(1:172,500,replace=T)))
mm <- ggplot(d, aes(x=nationality, colour=factor(course)))
mm + geom_bar() + theme_classic()
```

...but as said: I want a subset of the entire dataset based on frequency. The above shows all data.

PS. I added the ggplot2 code for context but also because maybe there is something within ggplot2 itself that would make this possible (I doubt it however).

**EDIT 2014-12-11:**
The current answers use ddplyr or table methods to arrive at the desired subset, but I wonder if there is not a more direct way to achieve the same.. I will let it stay for now, see if there are other ways.

Comment: Regarding your 'PS' and 'EDIT': It is generally much easier to _first_ prepare the data frame using your data massage tools of choice, _then_ call `ggplot`. [**This Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771022/ggplot2-geom-bar-plot-where-count-greater-than-x), which is similar to your case, is one of many examples of that. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr` functions `count` and `top_n` to get top-10 nationalities. Because `top_n` accounts for ties, the number of nationalities included in this example are more than 10 due to ties. `arrange` the counts, use `factor` and `levels` to set nationalities in descending order.

```
# top-10 nationalities
d2 <- d %>%
  count(nationality) %>%
  top_n(10) %>%
  arrange(n, nationality) %>%
  mutate(nationality = factor(nationality, levels = unique(nationality)))

d %>%
  filter(nationality %in% d2$nationality) %>%
  mutate(nationality = factor(nationality, levels = levels(d2$nationality))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = nationality, fill = course)) +
    geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. Just this afternoon I was looking into `dplyr` but realized I did not have the time to dive into it. Seems like q nice syntax, will look into it later.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach to select the top 10 nationalities. Note that multiple nationalities share the same frequency. Therefore, selecting the top 10 results in omitting some nationalities with the same frequency.

```
# calculate frequencies
tab <- table(d$nationality)
# sort
tab_s <- sort(tab)
# extract 10 most frequent nationalities
top10 <- tail(names(tab_s), 10)
# subset of data frame
d_s <- subset(d, nationality %in% top10)
# order factor levels
d_s$nationality <- factor(d_s$nationality, levels = rev(top10))

# plot
ggplot(d_s, aes(x = nationality, fill = as.factor(course))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  theme_classic()
```

Note that I changed `colour` to `fill` since `colour` affects the colour of the border.

[image]

Comment: this answer is more 'understandable' for me, but how would you order the ggplot results?

Answer (score 0):

although the questions was raised some time ago, I propose two other solutions for the sake of completeness:

```
d_raw <- data.frame(
  course = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500, replace = T),
  nationality = as.factor(sample(1:172, 500, replace=T))
)
```

1. One using `fct_lump_n()` from the forcats package and `filter()`

   ```
    d1 <- d_raw %>% 
      mutate(nationality = fct_lump_n(
        f = nationality, 
        n = 10,
        ties.method = "first"
      )) %>% 
      filter(nationality != "Other")

    d1 %>% count(nationality, sort = TRUE)

    ggplot(d1, aes(x = nationality, fill = course)) + # factor() is not needed here.
      geom_bar() + 
      theme_classic()
   ```

   `fct_lump_n()` summarises all nationalities except for the 10 most frequent ones to category "Other". Note that in `fct_lump_n()` argument `ties.method = "first"` is needed to really get only the first ten nationalities, not 11 or 12. All other nationalities are labeled "Other" even though they may appear just as often as the first ten nationalities.

   Levels of nationality are only ordered alphabetically.

   [image]
2. Another solution is using `fct_infreq()` from the forcats package, `cur_group_id()` and `filter()`.

   ```
    d2 <- d_raw %>% 
      group_by(nationality = fct_infreq(nationality)) %>% 
      filter(cur_group_id() <= 10) %>% 
      ungroup()

    d2 %>% count(nationality, sort = TRUE)

    ggplot(d2, aes(x = nationality, fill = course)) + # factor() is not needed here.
      geom_bar() + 
      theme_classic()
   ```

   `cur_group_id()` assigns a group ID to every nationality. To get started with the most frequent nationality we first need to order column `nationality` by its frequencies. Then we filter for the first ten group IDs aka the ten most frequent nationalities.

   Levels of nationality are first ordered by `n`, then ordered alphabetically.

   [image]

I used `count()` to verify the two data frames `d1` and `d2` look the same.
Both solutions have the advantage, that we don't need a second (temporary) data frame or temporary vectors.

I hope this helps someone in the future.